# C# mono GTK how to pack for Mac OS X

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, operating-system

I have developed an application on my Windows machine, using Xamarin Studio, targeting Mono / .Net 4.5 and using GTK. The app runs on my Windows machine since I have .Net installed, now I need to deploy to a Mac. The Mac has Mono Runtime already installed, but I have no idea what to send.

If there is anything I need to "pack" or "link" I need to do it on my Windows machine and only send one or more files to the Mac user, so they can run it. After hours of reading, I keep hearing about mkbundle and MonoMac, but it seems that you use them on a Mac or at least I have not found a clear guide on how to do this on my Windows computer.

Here is the question - I have only one .exe right now, how do I "convert" this to a Mac "executable?"

Comment: send your exe and your dll files and on the mac run it with `mono yourExeFile.exe`

Comment: Yes, I know how to run it from Terminal. You can't really ask the end-users to do that though. I want a double-clickable app and hopefully an installer, which checks if Mono is present and installs it if not.